# Why am I getting pymongo ServerSelectionTimeoutError?

Tags: django, mongodb, docker-compose

This is a small Django project using MongoDB as a database running with Docker. I am getting a pymongo ServerSelectionTimeoutError.

[image]

[image]

**docker-compose.yml**

I tried finding the solution with mongo shell using docker exec -it container_id bash but everthing seems fine in there. Command I use to start mongo shell inside a running container is **mongo -u signals -p insecure**

[image]

I also tried to connect to this database using MongoDB Compass and it worked. I am able to connect to MongoDB Compass. Connection string is **mongodb://signals:insecure@localhost:27017/webform**. I am able to see all the collections in MongoDB Compass but my Django application is not able to connect with database.

[image]

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'kv2ischvghz-st=13_-=1d=8ffpjsb_pi*9n%agi)k8w*g+70)'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

APPEND_SLASH=False
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'WebForm.signals',
   'rest_framework',
   'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'WebForm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
   {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': [],
      'APP_DIRS': True,
      'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
      },
   },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WebForm.wsgi.application'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
      'ENGINE': 'djongo',
      'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
      'NAME': 'webform',
      'HOST': 'mongodb',
      'PORT': 27017,
      'USER': 'signals',
      'PASSWORD': 'insecure',
      'AUTH_SOURCE': 'admin',
      'AUTH_MECHANISM': 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
  }         
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
  },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl-NL'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'l d-m-Y, H:i'  # e.g. "Donderdag 06-09-2018, 13:56"


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/signals/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**settings.py**

In settings.py file, I also tried different host name '**localhost**', '**127.0.0.1**' but still get same error again and again.

I am not able to understand the problem here docker containers are running fine, also able to connect to db using shell and mongodb compass but not my django application. Please help.
Let me know if any more information is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The issue is in the connection string host should be mongo not localhost ***mongodb://signals:insecure@mongo:27017/webform***. Also changed my database image name to mongo.